# Maven Build Javadoc Zip during mvn javadoc:javadoc

Tags: java, maven

I'm generating a ZIP of generated Javadoc during mvn install operation by using the following:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>docs-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}-Javadoc</finalName>
                  <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                  <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assemble.xml</descriptor>
                  </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

But if I want to generate this ZIP file by launching mvn javadoc:javadoc, the ZIP file is not generated:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>docs-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                      <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}-Javadoc</finalName>
                      <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                      <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assemble.xml</descriptor>
                      </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I Just copy / paste the execution but the docs-assembly is not executed with javadoc:javadoc...
why it is not called during javadoc:javadoc call ?

Comment: You are familiar with https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html ?

Comment: Javadoc plugin does not have a configuration with descriptor etc. that looks like a configuration for maven-assembly-plugin...

Comment: yes it seems javadoc plugin is quite limited for my need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main question is: why is `maven-assembly-plugin:single` not called during `javadoc:javadoc` call?
For this you need to understand the difference between lifecycles and plugin goals.
A plugin goal is a single task, easy to recognize by the colon. So `javadoc:javadoc` is a plugin goal.
Consider a lifecycle as an ordered group of plugin goals. You can call a lifecycle-phase (has no colons) and Maven knows which plugins need to be executed. `package` is a lifecycle-phase.

So if you are calling `javadoc:javadoc`, that will be the only task. There's no reason for Maven to also execute `maven-assembly-plugin:single`.

btw, did you try `javadoc:jar`? You should know that jar is just a zip file with extras.

Comment: Thanks that's right I didn't get the difference between lifecycles and goals. by using javadoc:jar the jar is correctly generated, I'll keep it a jar, I knew it was also a zip format.